# How to insert line in normal mode and stay at the same position

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I tried to bind the following to insert a line after the line I'm currently on. Here it is:

```
nnoremap <CR> o<ESC>k
```

But this works weird. After inserting a new line cursor is at the beginning of the line I was on.

Is there a way to insert a new line in normal mode and stay at the same position?

Comment: You can try `:nnoremap <CR> o`. This will add a newline and stay there itself

Comment: I was going to suggest using [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) but sadly its `[ Space` and `] Space` mappings suffer from the same problem you describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*That's odd, I was quite sure to have already answered this question twice. It may have been on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3171023/15934)...*

Anyway. Use `append()`. It won't move the cursor or alter more registers than necessary.

```
" This also supports counts. Try 3<cr>
:nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :<C-U>call append('.', repeat([''],v:count1))<cr>
```

Comment: I don't have time to search for the questions now but I do share your feeling of déjà vu.

Comment: It does support count, but does not work as expected. When counting e.g. `3<CR>` it moves the cursor 2 lines down. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @user3663882. Good catch. Here is a version that correctly supports repeat: `:nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :<C-U>call append('.', repeat([''],v:count1))<cr>`

Comment: Can this be modified to insert a newline above the current line?

Comment: @alxndr Of course. Use `line('.')-1` instead of `'.'` as the first parameter of `append()`

Answer (score 4):

Almost every time you move your cursor, the previous location is added to "the jumplist". Using `<C-o>` will move you back to the previous location in the jump list. From `:h CTRL-o`

```
                            *CTRL-O*
CTRL-O          Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list
            (not a motion command).
            {not in Vi}
            {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}
```

However, binding to

```
nnoremap <CR> o<ESC><C-o>
```

Does not work because `o` is one of the movements that doesn't add the previous location. To manually add the current location, type `` m` ``. From `` :h m` ``

```
                        *m'* *m`*
m'  or  m`      Set the previous context mark.  This can be jumped to
            with the "''" or "``" command (does not move the
            cursor, this is not a motion command).
```

So the end mapping would be

```
nnoremap <CR> m`o<ESC><C-o>
```

Actually, we can make this mapping even better! We can make it accept a count.

```
nnoremap <expr> <cr> "m`".v:count1."o\<esc>\<C-o>"
```