# Silently call a mapping that accepts a range

Tags: vimrc

I have the following function that I'm calling to insert blank lines under the cursor:

```
function InsertBlankLine()

    call LogOutput('*** START ***', "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
    " a: args will give us the following by default: -- see `:h: a:var`
    "   '0': '000': 'firstline': 109, 'lastline': 108 
    "   '0' is the number of extra arguments, '000' is the list of those extra args
    let data = a:
    call LogOutput("Data: " . string(data), "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})

    " Access a dict value get(dict, 'value')
    let first_line = get(a:, 'firstline')

    " Insert a new line
    call LogOutput('Executing normal o', "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
    execute "normal! o"

    " Go back to the first line
    let cmd = printf("normal! %sG", first_line)
    call LogOutput('Executing cmd: ' . cmd, "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
    execute cmd

endfunction
```

And I can call it like this with a shortcut:

```
nnoremap T :call InsertBlankLine()<CR>
```

So that I can type in `10T` and it will insert ten blank lines. This all works. However, it spits out a lot of input which I want to suppress using `silent`. However, I'm not sure how to pass `:silent` to the function as it will usually start with a number. For example, if I type in `10T`, this is the command it runs:

```
:.,.+9call InsertBlankLine()
```

So how would I get that to execute silently (without removing the LogOutput's ?
[image]

Comment: You're missing a `:` in `:call`...

Comment: @filbranden sorry, that was entered in on the cmd line. It works normally, for example `:.,.+9call InsertBlankLine()`. However, when I try and add a `silent` to the cmd it's erring.

Comment: There's a difference between `:.,.+9silent call ...` (shouldn't work) and `:silent .,.+9call ...` (I'm guessing this one works?) In any case, please [edit] your question to match what you actually tried to do.

Comment: @filbranden updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `append()`, it's silent and it doesn't move the cursor -- As I said in your *review* question, I found using `:normal` & co convoluted to alter buffer content. Vim functions have less side effects.

```
:nnoremap <silent> T :<c-u>call append('.', '')<cr>
```

It can even be used to insert multiple lines: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9720/626

```
:nnoremap <silent> T :<c-u>call append('.', repeat([''], v:count1))<cr>
```

Among the other things you were possibly searching, there is

- [`c_CTRL-U` to clear range](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9752/626) -- we don't want a range but a count only => we clear up to the start of the command-line
- [`:h :map-<silent>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-%3csilent%3e) to make the mapping silent

Comment: THANK YOU for the `:h :map-<silent>`. You're expert Finally I got an answer although I asked Google an XY problem.